# in python, how to use savetxt to save numpy ndarray and use loadtxt to load it back?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I can store ndarray in a text file like this :

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
>>> a
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
>>> np.savetxt('a.out',a,'%d')
```

then file a.out looks like this :

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

now, I can load it back :

```
>>> b = np.loadtxt('a.out','int')
>>> b
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

so far so good for (2, 3) array.
Now I want to do the same for (1, 2, 3) array.

```
>>> a = np.array([[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[3,2,1],[6,5,4]]])
>>> a
array([[[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6]],

       [[3, 2, 1],
        [6, 5, 4]]])
>>> np.savetxt('a.out',a,'%d')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ckim/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1160, in savetxt
    % (str(X.dtype), format))
TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('int64') and format specifier ('%d %d')
```

What is the correct way to store the array? and how can I load it back? I read the document but it is not well explaining about how to specify the format for a complex ndarray.

I tried (not document for '%s', '%sf', int32, int4, ..)

```
np.savetxt('a.out',a,'%s')
```

and it gives me a.out file

```
[1 2 3] [4 5 6]
[3 2 1] [6 5 4]
```

that's more like it, but I don't know how to load it. I tried below to no avail.

```
>>> b = np.loadtxt('a.out','%d')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ckim/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 873, in loadtxt
    dtype = np.dtype(dtype)
TypeError: data type "%d" not understood
>>> b = np.loadtxt('a.out','%s')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ckim/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 873, in loadtxt
    dtype = np.dtype(dtype)
TypeError: data type "%s" not understood
```

Please anybody help me with this. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason you want to save it as an ascii file?  Would a binary dump be acceptible?  If so, `np.save` or `np.savez` would be more appropriate ...

Comment: @mgilson, ok your link(duplicate) is very helpful. and thanks also for save and savez. (I didn't know it exists). I prefer human readable data (some possibilities to handle it with C/C++ program)

Comment: Fair enough.  As noted in the dupe question, `savetxt` doesn't really handle arrays of ndim > 2.  You could use [ndarray.tofile](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tofile.html).  As long as your C++ work is on a similar system (endianness and all that jazz -- which is fairly standard these days anyway), you shouldn't have too much problem reading it...

Comment: Even if you saved it with `C/C++` in mind you'd have to decide how to represent 3d as rows and columns.  `savetxt` writes a `csv` which is common enough.  There isn't a 3d standard.  The code for `savetxt` is easy to read - just iterate on the array and write each row as a formatted line.